# TDD on TCPClient and unwrap received message

Tags: c#, tdd, tcpclient

Here's my scenario.

I need to connect to a TCP Server and receive message from it. The message is encapsulated with start tag and end tag.

I want to implement it in TDD way, but I do not know where to start.

I have been doing the bowling game kata for some days now, but still can't apply it to real world case.

An example of it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your server implement something like `IServer`, let's say with event `SendData`.

Have your client side class with injectable server. Example:

```
public class client{
readonly IServer _server;
public client(IServer server){this._server = server;}
}
```

All that remains is creating a `client` `object` with a `mock` `IServer` in your tests. 
Note: this is testing the behavior of your client, not testing network.

Also, to do TDD, start with a test method like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ClientReceivesData()
{
 var mockServer = new Mock<IServer>();//fails, makes you create the interface
 var client = new Client(mockServer.Object); // fails, makes you create client

 mockServer.Raise(s=>s.SendData+=null).Returns("test"); 
 // makes you create an event in the interface. Please check the syntax

 client.Listen(); 
 //makes you have some code on the client side to listen to server data.

 Assert.AreEqual("test", client.ReceivedData);// one of the many ways of asserting
}
```

Comment: What if the server is not implemented at my side? The TCP server is implemented by another team, I'm supposed to connect via an IP and port number. Also, thank you for the fast reply.

Comment: Then you should have an interface/layer between your code and server. It's a good practice anyway.

Comment: Sorry could you please show that in the code? I can't really get the idea.